# Some special characters not displayed properly in a ǝɯɐuɹǝsn

Tags: bug, status-declined, android-app, display-names

For example, [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/179419/ben-is-ueq-backwards) when displayed in the Android app doesn't show the `ǝ` character properly  in the username:

[image: Screenshot]

This happens in their profile and on posts.

Android app version 1.0.18 on Samsung Galaxy S3 and Android version 4.1.2.

Comment: Doubt it's bug in the app code, more likely the device itself doesn't have the font.

Comment: You may be right - I just checked with Chrome and Internet browsers and it has the same issue.

Comment: Maybe you can install the fonts yourself, see [this](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s3/589989-install-fonts.html). Most the team here can do is strip out those characters, and doubt it's a good solution.

Comment: @ShadowWizard can app provide a font? If so, then even if it's not the app's fault, app could solve it...

Comment: @Mołot good point! Looks like [it's possible indeed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5634245/447356).

Comment: I wasn't expecting to see my own avatar when searching for something! (I wasn't searching for this though... Google Fu is leaving me!)

Comment: @ben Ha, great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version of Roboto delivered on Android phones (keep in mind different versions of the OS supply different versions of Roboto and different subsets of it...) including my 4.4 testing device don't include this character, the [schwa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa).

The version of Roboto I have downloaded locally from the Google design guide includes it, but it's a serious amount of effort to put in extra fonts on android devices, we're doing it some places already but I *really* don't want to do it everywhere just to fix this.